# Pass IIF Expression's Results to Another Query's Criteria

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to pass the result of a select query to another query's criteria.  Where I'm struggling is passing a complex value that contains an operator.  I'm not even sure it's possible to pass an operator and have the next query recognize it.  I've tried similar to the code snippet below to no avail.  I can't seem to get the third result to work ("A or B").  Essentially the select query is a parameters query and based on a user's specifications grabs the values to be used in another query that displays results on a form.

```
IIf([field1]="1","A",IIf([field1]="2","B",IIf([field1]="3","A or B","Like *")))
```

Comment: You cannot do that unfortunately, you need VBA to perform this sort of operation.

Comment: Thanks for ruining my morning, Paul. ;)

Comment: Perhaps try & change the criteria to exclusive couplets; `(XXX Like '*' AND [field1] > 3) OR (XXX = "A" AND field1 = 1) ...`

Comment: My pleasure David ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using an iif in the criteria of the second query which solved the problem.

```
Like IIf([Q1]![F1]=1,1) Or Like IIf([Q1]![F1]=2,2) Or Like IIf([Q1]![F1]=12,Right([Q1]![F1],1)) Or Like IIf([Q1]![F1]=12,Left([Q1]![F1],1)) Or Like IIf([Q1]![F1]=123,"*")
```

Essentially if the value was '12', it would parse the result using right and left into '1 Or 2' as the criteria  with a proper operator allowing for both values to be returned in the query.